# Is there any way to keep the dirty bit in x86 page tables coherent without TLB invalidates?

Tags: x86, x86-64, cpu-architecture, tlb, page-tables

The Intel manual contains this admonishment (sec. 4.8):

> A processor may cache information from the paging-structure entries in TLBs and paging-structure caches (see Section 4.10).  This fact implies that, if software changes an accessed flag or a dirty flag from 1 to 0, the processor might not set the corresponding bit in memory on a subsequent access using an affected linear address (see Section 4.10.4.3).  See Section 4.10.4.2 for how software can ensure that these bits are updated as desired.

This would seem to indicate that, after clearing the dirty bit in a page table entry, if I would like to be able to examine it in the future and get useful results, I need a TLB invalidate/shootdown.  Is this true?  Is there any alternative—some way to effectively clean the TLB entry in place if it exists?

Comment: No, there's no way to clear the dirty bit in a TLB entry. You have to evict the entry to be sure that the dirty bit will be set the next time the page is written.

Comment: Some software does get useful results for A bits without doing the TLB evictions. It just accepts that some percentage of cleared bits will be cached and the A bit won't get set in the PTE. I think Linux does this. Of course that wouldn't work for the D  bit, if it is used to determine whether the contents of the page can be discarded.